# Using libdc1394 in XCode/Mac OS 10.9 gives linker errors - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, libdc1394

I am gearing up to use libdc1394 for camera capture on Mac OS 10.9/XCode5 and I am running into Apple Mach-O Linker Errors.  I am working off of what seemed to be good [instructions](http://notes.binarytree.org/articles/47/libdc1394-and-xcode) for libdc1394 and XCode, and was successful in locating libdc1394.dylib, including , and getting to hello world, which should mean everything is properly connected.

I am new to XCode Development so please be detailed in your answer if possible!  I understand that this may have something to do with the targeting of the build.

---

The next step was to build a simple example ([grab_color_image.c](https://github.com/astraw/libdc1394/blob/master/libdc1394/examples/grab_color_image.c)), but I am getting a ton of linker errors, starting with anything in `void cleanup_and_exit(dc1394camera_t *camera)`, which I commented out:

```
void cleanup_and_exit(dc1394camera_t *camera)
{
//    dc1394_video_set_transmission(camera, DC1394_OFF);
//    dc1394_capture_stop(camera);
//    dc1394_camera_free(camera);
//    exit(1);
}
```

**For example, uncommenting the first line above gives:**
*Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_dc1394_video_set_transmission", referenced from: cleanup_and_exit(__dc1394_camera**) *in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*

---

Below I tried to move further in the program, leaving the stuff above commented out ...

**The program below gives a similar error at `d = dc1394_new ();`:**   *Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_dc1394_new", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dc1394/dc1394.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <dc1394/dc1394.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#ifndef _WIN32
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#define IMAGE_FILE_NAME "image.ppm"

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Releases the cameras and exits
 *-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void cleanup_and_exit(dc1394camera_t *camera)
{
//    dc1394_video_set_transmission(camera, DC1394_OFF);
//    dc1394_capture_stop(camera);
//    dc1394_camera_free(camera);
//    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE* imagefile;
    dc1394camera_t *camera;
    unsigned int width, height;
    dc1394video_frame_t *frame=NULL;
    //dc1394featureset_t features;
    dc1394_t * d;
    dc1394camera_list_t * list;
    dc1394error_t err;

    d = dc1394_new ();    // <-- THIS gives a linker error, the above stuff is fine
//    if (!d)
//        return 1;
//    err=dc1394_camera_enumerate (d, &list);
//    DC1394_ERR_RTN(err,"Failed to enumerate cameras");


    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

As I mentioned before, I am altogether new to XCode development, and suspect it may have something to do with the "build target", but it's not totally obvious.  Here is a snapshot of some basic info (sorry it is a bit blurry):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to click the checkbox on target membership for libdc1394.dylib.

Clicking libdc1394.dylib on the left side of XCode brings up this on the right side.  I needed to add target membership.  Although in the initial part of the instructions #include  worked, it didn't later because the dylib library wasn't linked to the project, and thus the symbols weren't defined for the linker. (or something like that ...)

[image]